# How to send form string data and image data in a single Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How do you merge two Ajax calls so that they pass form input data as well as form image data using the formData API?

View Ajax Calls:

```
$("#submitbmsymptom").click(function(h){
    h.preventDefault();
    var radioValue;
    $('#radio1, #radio2, #radio3, #radio4').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            radioValue = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    console.log(radioValue +
    $("#bmdate").val() +
    $("#bmtime").val() +
    $("#bmscale").val() +
    $("#bmpainlevel").val() +
    $("#bmobs").val()
    );

    $.ajax({
        url:'urllocation',
        method: 'POST',
            data:{
                bmdate_data : $("#bmdate").val(),
                bmtime_data : $("#bmtime").val(),   
                bmscale_data : $("#bmscale").val(),
                bmcontents_data : radioValue,
                bmpainlevel_data : $("#bmpainlevel").val(),
                bmobs_data : $("#bmobs").val(),
            },
        }
        ).done(function(regresult){

    });
})

$("#submitbmsymptom").click(function(h){
    h.preventDefault();

    var pooPicture = $('input[name=poopic]');
    var fileUpload = pooPicture[0].files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", fileUpload);

    $.ajax({
        url:'urllocation',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function() {
            alert("File uploaded");
        }
    });
})
```

Controller Method that receives data, saves the file to server and then inserts the string data and file name into a database using an associative array:

```
function bowelmovements(){
    $bmuserid = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $bmsymptomdate = $this->input->post('bmdate_data');
    $bmsymptomtime = $this->input->post('bmtime_data');
    $bmsymptomtype = $this->input->post('bmscale_data');
    $bmsymptomlocation = $this->input->post('bmcontents_data');
    $bmsymptompainlevel = $this->input->post('bmpainlevel_data');
    $bmsymptomobs = $this->input->post('bmobs_data');

    $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'/assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|mp4";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload("file")){
        $imageData = $this->upload->data();
        $fileName = $imageData[file_name];
        $bmdata = array(
            'userid' => $bmuserid,
            'bmdate' => $bmsymptomdate ,
            'bmtime' => $bmsymptomtime,
            'bmscale' => $bmsymptomtype,
            'bmcontents' => $bmsymptomlocation ,
            'bmpainlevel' => $bmsymptompainlevel,
            'bmobs' => $bmsymptomobs,
            'bmimage' => $fileName
        );

    $insertBM = $this->poomonitormodel->insertBM($bmdata);
    }
    else{
        echo "File not uploaded";
    }

}
```

Currently this only submits the second Ajax call, and inserts only the file name into the database however I require both sets of data to submit into the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I condensed your 2 ajax calls into a single one:

```
$("#submitbmsymptom").click(function(h){
    h.preventDefault();
    var radioValue;
    $('#radio1, #radio2, #radio3, #radio4').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            radioValue = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    var pooPicture = $('input[name=poopic]');
    var fileUpload = pooPicture[0].files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", fileUpload);
    formData.append("bmdate_data", $("#bmdate").val());
    formData.append("bmtime_data", $("#bmtime").val());
    formData.append("bmscale_data", $("#bmscale").val());
    formData.append("bmcontents_data", radioValue);
    formData.append("bmpainlevel_data", $("#bmpainlevel").val());
    formData.append("bmobs_data", $("#bmobs").val());

    $.ajax({
        url:'urllocation',
        method: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
    }).done(function(regresult){

    });
});
```

Comment: I've fixed the invocation error, it was to do with not providing declaring contentType/ processData as false, however it's not extracting the image in the controller. I would assume it requires accessing differently.

Comment: @gideveloper - the only undefined type error I got when testing was: `TypeError: pooPicture[0] is undefined`, is this the same you are getting?

Comment: Nope, never had such error as that. As I posted above I corrected the first issue using `contentType:False, dataType: False` However i'm not receiving any data in my controller to execute the remainder of the function such as saving the file.

Comment: I added it into the above answer. give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately not, it requires the formData API, which i'm not aware of how to extract in the controller, the data is passed to the controller completely fine. However when it gets there and I use the `$this->input->post('file');` it's not recognizing it as a image file and therefore will not save the image to the server.

Comment: @gideveloper - added in the form data & format & also cleaned up the code a bit

Comment: I'm such a doughnut, I was thinking to try that from the start! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: No problem :) glad I could help.